# Numerical trade offs between 1/sqrt(x) and std::exp(-0.5 * std::log(x))

Tags: c++, c++11, numbers, floating-accuracy

I have come across some old code that computes

```
double y = 1 / std::sqrt(x);
```

Using:

```
constexpr double base16 = 16.0;
double log_base16 = std::log(base16);
double y = std::pow(base16, -0.5 * std::log(x) / log_base16);
```

Which is essentially:

```
double y = std::exp(-0.5 * std::log(x));
```

Is there any justifications with regard to numerical benefits (such as accuracy or more likely to avoid underflow/overflow) between the methods? The original author may have thought so.

Comment: How old can it be? `constexpr` was standardized in 2011.

Comment: @Potatoswatte I cleaned up the syntax to make the example as clear for people as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code is to be considered to be very naughty indeed, particularly in modern C++ standards and IEEE754 floating point:

> std::sqrt is required by the IEEE standard be exact. [sic.]

Furthermore, `std::pow` has *no* such requirements.

Therefore I'd be tempted to rewrite it as `1 / std::sqrt(x)`, testing of course.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt

Comment: Mind you, "exact" can come at a price. It's theoretically possible that the alternative code is faster. That said, it's _very_ theoretical. The only fast logarithms are base 2 and powers thereof, and the same holds for exponentiation. `2^(log2(x)/2)` is probably a lot faster than the old code.

Comment: @MSalters Sure, an xor would be faster, but for most values would be less accurate.

Comment: @Yakk: Shorthand for `std::exp2(std::log2(x)/2))`

Comment: @MSalters No, `^` is xor in C++.  Keep up!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any particularly good reasons for implementing sqrt() in terms of pow() and log(). It could be that there was a bug in the implementation of sqrt() and this was used as a workaround.

In general, I would expect this implementation to be slower and less precise.

Comment: Given `1 / std::sqrt(x)`, I'm pretty sure we can assume `x>0`